# question() NameError: name 'question' is not defined

Tags: python

```
import os
def menu():
    print("                            HELLO, WELCOME TO QUIZ GAME")
    print("\n press 1 for start")
    print("\n press 2 for exit")
    choice = input("Enter your choice : ")
    os.system('cls')         
    if choice == '1':
        question()
    elif choice == '2':
        os.system('cls')
    else:
        print("Invalid Choice")         
menu() 


def question():
    global total
    total = 0
    def question1():
        global total
        print(r"QUESTION 1. Pointing to a photograph, a man said, 'I have no brother, and that man's father is my father's son.' Whose photograph was it?")
        print("\n A.His son                             C.His father ")
        print("\n B.His own                             D.His nephew")
        answer = input("Enter Your ans : ")
        if answer == 'A':
            total+=50
            print("Correct answer")
        else:
            total-=30
            print("Wrong answer")   
    question1()
    input("Press enter to continue ;)")
    os.system('cls')    

    def question2():
        global total
        print(r"QUESTION.2 If * means /, - means *, / means + and + means -, then (3 - 15 / 19) * 8 + 3 = ?") 
        print("\n A.-1                                C.2 ")
        print("\n B.8                                 D.1 ") 
        answer = input("Enter Your ans : ")
        if answer == 'D':
            total+=50
            return print("Corrrect answer")
        else:
            total-=30
            print(total)
            return print("Wrong answer")
    question2() 
    input("Press enter to continue ;)")
    os.system('cls')

    def question3():
        global total
        print(r"QUESTION.3 Find the letter in the 8th position when the alphabets are written in  reverse alphabetical order ?")
        print("\n A.A                                     C.B ")
        print("\n B.S                                     D.E ")
        answer = input("Enter your ans : ")
        if answer == 'C':
            total+=50
            print("Correct answer")
        else:
            total-=30
            print("wrong answer")
    question3()  
    input("Press enter to continue ;)")
    os.system('cls')

    def question4():
        global total
        print(r"QUESTION.4 In the following question, select the odd word from the given alternatives.") 
        print("\n A.Neurologist                          C.Dentist")
        print("\n B.Architect                            D.Pediatrician") 
        answer = input("Enetr your ans : ")
        if answer == 'B':
            total+=50
            print("Coreect Answer")
        else:
            total-=30
            print("Wrong Answer")
        print(total)    
    question4()
    input("Press enter to continue ;)")
    os.system("cls")

    def question5():
        global total
        print(r"QUESTION.5 Use the relations defined below and answer the following question \n A + B means A is the mother of B. \n A - B means A is the sister of B. \n A * B means A is the father of B. \n A / B means A is the son of B. \n A = B means A is the brother of B. \n A != B means A is the daughter of B.")
        print("\n A.P - R / Q                             C.P + R * Q")
        print("\n B.P != R * Q                            D.P - R + Q")
        answer = input("Enter Your ans : ")
        if answer == 'D':
            total+=50
            print("Correct Answer")
        else:
            total-=30
            print("wrong answer")
        print(total)
    question5()
    input("Press enter to continue ;)")
    os.system("cls")

    def question6():
        global total
        print(r"QUESTION 6. A's mother's son's only sister is B. How is A related to C, if B is the mother of C's daughter ?") 
        print("\n A.Brother                                C.Brother-in-law")
        print("\n B.uncle                                  D.Nephew") 
        answer = input("Enetr your ans : ")
        if answer == 'C':
            total+=50
            print("Correct answer")
        else:
            total-=30
            print("Wrong answer")
        print(total)
    question6()
    input("Press enter to continue ;)")
    os.system('cls')

    def question7():
        global total
        print("QUESTION.7 If in a certain code language, 'oka peru' means 'fine cloth' ; 'meta lisa' means 'clear water' and 'dona lisa peru' means 'fine clear weather' , which word in that language means 'weather'?")
        print("\n A.peru                                   C.oka")
        print("\n B.meta                                   D.dona") 
        answer = input("Enter your answer : ")
        if answer == 'D':
            total+=50
            print("Correct answer")
        else:
            total-=30
            print("wrong answer")
    question7()
    input("Press enter to continue ;)")
    os.system('cls')

    def question8():
        global total
        print("QUESTION.8 Radiant : Brilliant :: Zenith : ?") 
        print("\n A.Peak                                 C.Cheerful")
        print("\n B.Misery                               D.Abet")
        answer = input("Enetr Your ans : ")
        if answer == 'A':
            total+=50
            print("Correct answer")
        else:
            total-=30
            print("wrong answer")
    question8()
    input("Press enetr to continue ;)")
    os.system('cls')

    def question9():
        global total
        print("QUESTION.9 69 - 51 + 62 * 61 / 54")
        print("\n A.94.04                                C.88.04")
        print("\n B.92.04                                D.85.04")
        answer = input("Enter your ans : ")
        if answer == 'C':
            total+=50
            print("Correct answer")
        else:
            total-=30
            print("Wrong answer")
    question9()
    input("Press enter to continue;)")
    os.system('cls')

    def question10():
        global total
        print("QUESTION.10 Vinu buys Rs. 40 shares paying 9 % dividend. He wants to have an interest of 12% of his money. Find the market value of each share")
        print("\n A.30                                    C.65")
        print("\n B.85                                    D.33")
        answer = input("Enter your ans : ")
        if answer == 'A':
            total+=50
            print("Correct answer")
        else:
            total-=30
            print("Wrong answer") 
    question10()    

    print("Your point is : ",total)
    if total == 500:
        print("You won 1 lakh ")
    elif total >= 400 and total <500:  
        print("You Won 50K")
    elif total >= 300 and total < 400:
        print("You Won 25K")
    elif total >= 200 and total < 300:
        print("You Won 10K")
    else:
        print("Sorry,better luck next time ")                         

# question()     


input("Press enter to exit ;)")
```

Comment: You call `menu()` at a point before `question()` is defined.

Comment: You can move `menu()` just above your `input("Press enter to exit ;)")`

Answer (score 1):

Call `menu()` after you have defined the `question()` method, i.e. before `input("Press enter to exit ;)")`

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, name `question` has not been defined when you call `menu()`. So simply change it to:

```py
import os
def menu():
    print("                            HELLO, WELCOME TO QUIZ GAME")
    print("\n press 1 for start")
    print("\n press 2 for exit")
    choice = input("Enter your choice : ")
    os.system('cls')         
    if choice == '1':
        question()
    elif choice == '2':
        os.system('cls')
    else:
        print("Invalid Choice")         



def question():
    global total
    total = 0
    def question1():
        global total
        print(r"QUESTION 1. Pointing to a photograph, a man said, 'I have no brother, and that man's father is my father's son.' Whose photograph was it?")
        print("\n A.His son                             C.His father ")
        print("\n B.His own                             D.His nephew")
        answer = input("Enter Your ans : ")
        if answer == 'A':
            total+=50
            print("Correct answer")
        else:
            total-=30
            print("Wrong answer")   
    question1()
    input("Press enter to continue ;)")
    os.system('cls')    

    def question2():
        global total
        print(r"QUESTION.2 If * means /, - means *, / means + and + means -, then (3 - 15 / 19) * 8 + 3 = ?") 
        print("\n A.-1                                C.2 ")
        print("\n B.8                                 D.1 ") 
        answer = input("Enter Your ans : ")
        if answer == 'D':
            total+=50
            return print("Corrrect answer")
        else:
            total-=30
            print(total)
            return print("Wrong answer")
    question2() 
    input("Press enter to continue ;)")
    os.system('cls')

    def question3():
        global total
        print(r"QUESTION.3 Find the letter in the 8th position when the alphabets are written in  reverse alphabetical order ?")
        print("\n A.A                                     C.B ")
        print("\n B.S                                     D.E ")
        answer = input("Enter your ans : ")
        if answer == 'C':
            total+=50
            print("Correct answer")
        else:
            total-=30
            print("wrong answer")
    question3()  
    input("Press enter to continue ;)")
    os.system('cls')

    def question4():
        global total
        print(r"QUESTION.4 In the following question, select the odd word from the given alternatives.") 
        print("\n A.Neurologist                          C.Dentist")
        print("\n B.Architect                            D.Pediatrician") 
        answer = input("Enetr your ans : ")
        if answer == 'B':
            total+=50
            print("Coreect Answer")
        else:
            total-=30
            print("Wrong Answer")
        print(total)    
    question4()
    input("Press enter to continue ;)")
    os.system("cls")

    def question5():
        global total
        print(r"QUESTION.5 Use the relations defined below and answer the following question \n A + B means A is the mother of B. \n A - B means A is the sister of B. \n A * B means A is the father of B. \n A / B means A is the son of B. \n A = B means A is the brother of B. \n A != B means A is the daughter of B.")
        print("\n A.P - R / Q                             C.P + R * Q")
        print("\n B.P != R * Q                            D.P - R + Q")
        answer = input("Enter Your ans : ")
        if answer == 'D':
            total+=50
            print("Correct Answer")
        else:
            total-=30
            print("wrong answer")
        print(total)
    question5()
    input("Press enter to continue ;)")
    os.system("cls")

    def question6():
        global total
        print(r"QUESTION 6. A's mother's son's only sister is B. How is A related to C, if B is the mother of C's daughter ?") 
        print("\n A.Brother                                C.Brother-in-law")
        print("\n B.uncle                                  D.Nephew") 
        answer = input("Enetr your ans : ")
        if answer == 'C':
            total+=50
            print("Correct answer")
        else:
            total-=30
            print("Wrong answer")
        print(total)
    question6()
    input("Press enter to continue ;)")
    os.system('cls')

    def question7():
        global total
        print("QUESTION.7 If in a certain code language, 'oka peru' means 'fine cloth' ; 'meta lisa' means 'clear water' and 'dona lisa peru' means 'fine clear weather' , which word in that language means 'weather'?")
        print("\n A.peru                                   C.oka")
        print("\n B.meta                                   D.dona") 
        answer = input("Enter your answer : ")
        if answer == 'D':
            total+=50
            print("Correct answer")
        else:
            total-=30
            print("wrong answer")
    question7()
    input("Press enter to continue ;)")
    os.system('cls')

    def question8():
        global total
        print("QUESTION.8 Radiant : Brilliant :: Zenith : ?") 
        print("\n A.Peak                                 C.Cheerful")
        print("\n B.Misery                               D.Abet")
        answer = input("Enetr Your ans : ")
        if answer == 'A':
            total+=50
            print("Correct answer")
        else:
            total-=30
            print("wrong answer")
    question8()
    input("Press enetr to continue ;)")
    os.system('cls')

    def question9():
        global total
        print("QUESTION.9 69 - 51 + 62 * 61 / 54")
        print("\n A.94.04                                C.88.04")
        print("\n B.92.04                                D.85.04")
        answer = input("Enter your ans : ")
        if answer == 'C':
            total+=50
            print("Correct answer")
        else:
            total-=30
            print("Wrong answer")
    question9()
    input("Press enter to continue;)")
    os.system('cls')

    def question10():
        global total
        print("QUESTION.10 Vinu buys Rs. 40 shares paying 9 % dividend. He wants to have an interest of 12% of his money. Find the market value of each share")
        print("\n A.30                                    C.65")
        print("\n B.85                                    D.33")
        answer = input("Enter your ans : ")
        if answer == 'A':
            total+=50
            print("Correct answer")
        else:
            total-=30
            print("Wrong answer") 
    question10()    

    print("Your point is : ",total)
    if total == 500:
        print("You won 1 lakh ")
    elif total >= 400 and total <500:  
        print("You Won 50K")
    elif total >= 300 and total < 400:
        print("You Won 25K")
    elif total >= 200 and total < 300:
        print("You Won 10K")
    else:
        print("Sorry,better luck next time ")                         

# question()     
menu() 

input("Press enter to exit ;)")
```